# enable extjs loadmask Iframe while processing

Tags: iframe, extjs, extjs4.2

I'm trying to set a loadmask for an extjs4 Iframe while generating a pdf report

```
var WinReporte=Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
        title: 'Reporte de Clientes',
        width: 750,
        height: 400,
        layout: 'fit',
        xtype: 'panel',
        modal:true,

         html:'<iframe src="pdf.php" onLoad="javascript:window.parent.WinReporte.body.unmask();" style="height:100%;width:100%"></iframe>', 

        listeners: {
            show: function(){
                WinReporte.body.mask('Creating report...please wait!')
            },

        } 


    });
```

I got a typo error in console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined 
so the loadmask never hide

Is there anything glaringly wrong here?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks good, you can also would be use :

```
WinReporte.setLoading( true )
WinReporte.setLoading( false )
```

[docs setLoading](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-setLoading)